# How to get values from HTML radio buttons inside a repeater?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a simple questionnaire system which shows a random number of questions to the user out of a certain total in my database.

I have 2 separate tables: `Questions` and `Alternatives` (which are the options to answer) related by `QuestionID` field in both tables. I rendered such questionnaire using **Nested Repeaters** (*parentRepeater* for questions and *childRepeater* for the options) and it shows correctly on the page.

Each option is a radio button which I had to use it as a HTML instead of the *Standard Server Control* `<asp:RadioButton>` because of the Dynamic ID problem inside a repeater.

So my `.aspx` code is like this:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptQuestoes" runat="server">
                    <HeaderTemplate>
                        <form method="get">
                        <ol class="orderedList">
                    </HeaderTemplate>

                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <li>
                            <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "QuestionName")%>
                            <asp:Repeater ID="rptAlternativas" DataSource='<%# Container.DataItem.Row.GetChildRows("Questionario") %>' runat="server">
                                <HeaderTemplate>
                                    <ul style="list-style-type: none">
                                </HeaderTemplate>

                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <li>
                                        <input id="<%#Container.DataItem("AlternativeID")%>" type="radio" runat="server" name="<%#Container.DataItem("QuestionID")%>" value="<%#Container.DataItem("AlternativeID")%>" /><%#Container.DataItem("AlternativeName")%>
                                    </li>
                                </ItemTemplate>

                                <FooterTemplate>
                                    </ul>
                                </FooterTemplate>
                            </asp:Repeater>
                        </li>
                    </ItemTemplate>

                    <FooterTemplate>
                        </ol>
                        </form>
                    </FooterTemplate>
                </asp:Repeater>
```

What I don't know is how do I get all the questions answered by the user given that I don't know the `QuestionID`s and the `AlternativeID`s since it's randomly generated and using a HTML `input` tags?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to access them from `Request.Form["nameoftheRadioButtonYouWant"];`

I don't know what is coming out of your Repeater, but with this structure:

```
<input type="radio" value="someRadio" name="A" />
<input type="radio" value="hello" name="A" />
<input type="radio" value="world" name="A" />
```

Checking the middle radio produces "Hello" for this code:

```
string aVal = Request.Form["A"];
```

So it looks like from your code you'll be looping through all your questions, and finding the answer the user selected from

```
string answer = Request.Form[QuesId.ToString()]; //don't forget the ToString()!
```

Since your giving the radio buttons the name of the questionid

```
<input ... type="radio" name="<%#Container.DataItem("QuestionID")%>"
```

Comment: Nice, but do I need the `<form>` tag or anything in special as shown in the HeaderTemplate? With this tag, the Button to proccess it doesn't work

Comment: Oh, I didn't notice that.  Yeah, you definitely want to get rid of that form tag in the header.  Just have everything be a part of the main form on your page, and when you post back, you can read all the values from Request.Form

Comment: What if I don't know the `QuestionIDs` to recover ('cause it's randomly generated)? How do I loop through every `input radio`? Is there any Indexer I can use in my Repeater? Thx

Comment: @Rodrigo -  I don't think you can loop through every input radio in your code behind.  I think you'll have to find a way to get those question ids to not be random.